# Regex - 1st group 1 time, 2nd group Multiple times

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, split

I have data like -

> 06deepaksharma

i need regex to split the data as

> 06 > then multiple group of (06 char)

so its going to be like 
first 2 digit then multiple groups, each with the length of first 2 digit value.

```
01DE     >     01   D     E                        01 - then 2 group each 1 char length
02DE     >     02   DE                             02 - then 1 group each 2 char length
02DESH   >     02   DE    SH                       02 - then 2 group each 2 char length
03DEESHA >     03   DEE   SHA                      03 - then 2 group each 3 char length
01DEESHA >     01   D     E     E    S    H   A    01 - then 6 group each 1 char length
```

Hope now its clear what i want. 
I am not getting how to fix the length for second group on the basis of first group value and how to define that second group may occur N times.

> UPDATE BELOW  ---

so if we can not apply the length on second group then can we get all the possibility if I say i fix the length of second group?

mean if length going to be 2 for char groups

```
01DE        >  01   DE
01DEEPAK    >  01   DE  EP   AK
XXDEEP      >  XX   DE  EP
```

So if we say length going to be 2 all the times, now can be get the desired result as stated in `UPDATED` parts

Comment: It's clear what you want, but I don't think it's possible. to use [back references](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#namedgroups) like that.

Comment: I think you should split the string into 2 parts and then parse the number and compare with length of other part to check consistency. Regex here might be a bit too much (for just splitting a string every x letters) and too less (getting a length to use inside the regex).

Comment: yes, so to remove the back reference, if I fix the length of the second group.  now I need to split first 2 digit. then multiple group, each of 2 char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you described in the beginning of your question with both regex and LINQ:

```
var input = "03DEESHA";
var result = new List<string>();
var mtch = Regex.Match(input, @"^(\d+)(.*)"); // Get the Match object with captured texts
result.Add(mtch.Groups[1].Value);             // Add the number to the resulting list
var chunks = Regex.Matches(mtch.Groups[2].Value,   // Get all chunks
   string.Format(".{{{0}}}", int.Parse(mtch.Groups[1].Value)))
          .Cast<Match>()
          .Select(p => p.Value)
          .ToList();
result.AddRange(chunks);
```

The regex `^(\d+)(.*)` matches any numbers in the beginning (Group 1), and then captures the rest of a single-line string (with no newlines, if you want to support them, add a `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag to the `Regex.Match`) into Group 2.

Result of the above code execution:

[image]

If you have strings where the number of the letters cannot be divided by the initial number without a remainder, instead of `".{{{0}}}"` use `".{{1,{0}}}"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think you can use regex here as you need to use a back-ref with variable value.

However you may consider a simple linq on the characters:

```
// first get the number of characters to read
int num = Convert.ToInt32(myString.Substring(0, 2));

// now a simple loop on the characters
for(int i = 2; i < myString.Length; i += num) result.Add(myString.SubString(i, num);
```

Or if you really want a regex parse the number first and THEN apply your regex:

```
var r = "([a-zA-Z]{" + num + "})";
var res = new Regex(r).Split(new string(myString.Skip(2).ToArray()));
```

Comment: so to remove the back reference, if I fix the length of the second group. now I need to split first 2 digit. then multiple group, each of 2 char.

Comment: i tried the regex like above.. but that is capturing only last second group.. for 01ABCD - it will return 01 and CD.  But i want 01, AB and CD. all

Comment: I´ve updated my answer, still prints out some empty results within the `res`-list, but you may filter them easily out with a `where`-filter.